# Duplicate a branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

How can I duplicate a branch in Mercurial? I need the new branch to be against head (as the first one is).

The GIT equivalent (if I was in branch-a) would be:

```
git checkout -b branch-b
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want / need to do this?

Comment: I'm no git expert, but I don't think that git checkout -b "duplicates" a branch. It seems to just create a new one?

Comment: @DaveInCaz it creates a new one with the same commits. That's what I meant by 'duplicate'.

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate all the commits? Can't you just branch off from a convenient starting point of the original commits?

Comment: Essentially I want to take the work I've already done but be free to work on the task in a different way. Id like the possibility of deleting the original branch without affecting the new branch. I also want to see all the changes (against master) in the new branch.

Comment: Check out topic branches, which are part of the Evolve extension. Consider using Evolve if you are not already doing so. While Evolve is an extension, it's an officially supported part of Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

A Mercurial branch is a named entity that consists of all the commits contained within the branch.  So in order to duplicate some existing branch, you must also duplicate all of its commits to new commits that are in the new branch.  We then get into [metaphysics arguments about commit identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)  It's probably not a good idea to go here at all, but if you *do* want to go here, use `hg graft` to *copy* all the desired commits into the new branch.

A Git branch consists of a name containing a raw commit hash ID.  So duplicating a Git branch under a new name is trivial.  Note that the set of branches that contain any given commit changes dynamically over time: a branch that was only on `feature/tall` may now only be on `master`, even though that commit is still that commit, even via most of these metaphysical arguments.  (Only the "no identity over time" argument lets us claim that this is not the same commit.)

Another way to put it is that Mercurial's branches actually *mean* something, but Git's don't.  If you need true branches, you can't use Git in the first place.  Don't try to import Git's bizzareness into Mercurial: you'll just make your own life miserable.

Meanwhile, though, Mercurial contains a DAG just like Git.  If you use Mercurial bookmarks, those work like Git branches.  It's probably wiser, then, to just use bookmarks and be done with it.

If all else fails, see `hg graft`.

Comment: indeed, it cannot be emphasized enough that a hg branch is not a git branch. The equivalent of git branch is hg bookmark. Along with that: in hg it's not necessary to name branches as it is with git... anonymous heads just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> the new branch to be against head

What is *this* (in usual business-term, not Git-lingua)? While in common (and in details) @torek is totally right, he forgot to write exact command-set, something like

```
hg up <rev-id>
hg branch <new-branch-name>
hg graft -r "branch(old-branch-name)" --log
```